# Getting Data from MS SQL Database to Xamarin Android App Gridview

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, xamarin

I am new to Mobile Development and I am currently learning Xamarin. I would like to ask for guide on how I can integrate my MS SQL Database to my Xamarin Android App.

Like, I want to get data from a table and pass it to a gridview in Xamarin.

Please enlighten me.

Thanks,

Kim

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very generic, if you are taking about connecting to offline db, that would be SQLite not MS SQL.

If you want to leverage MS SQL, you would have to have service layer that would communicate with MS SQL db, and you would get that data through rest based services in JSON/XML format.

Comment: I get it now Mr. Kumar. Thank you.